# Keras with Tensoflow backend allocates GPU memory but does not use GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with the Tensorflow backend. When running nvidia-smi I can see that python allocates memory on the GPU, but it does not seem to use it otherwise. Also the calculations are running really slow (~ 300 seconds instead of ~ 15). I am using a GTX 980.

My Python 3 code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# ## Set up Libraries

import keras as K
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten, Lambda
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


# ## Code

def one_hot(x):
    matrix = np.zeros([x.size, np.max(x) + 1])
    matrix[np.arange(x.size), x] = 1
    return matrix


# ## Prepare Data

from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, Y_train_raw), (X_test, Y_test_raw) = mnist.load_data()


X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 3)
Y_train_raw = np.expand_dims(Y_train_raw, 3)
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, 3)
Y_test_raw = np.expand_dims(Y_test_raw, 3)


mnist_mean = X_train.mean().astype(np.float32)
mnist_stddev = X_train.std().astype(np.float32)
def normalize_mnist_input(x):
    return (x - mnist_mean) / mnist_stddev


Y_train = one_hot(Y_train_raw)
Y_test = one_hot(Y_test_raw)


X_valid = X_train[50000:]
Y_valid = X_train[50000:]
X_train = X_train[0:50000]
Y_train = Y_train[0:50000]


# ## Fit Simple Model

def linear_model():
    model = Sequential([
        Lambda(normalize_mnist_input, input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ])
    model.compile(Adam(), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

linear_model = linear_model()


image_generator = ImageDataGenerator()
train_batches = image_generator.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=64)
test_batches = image_generator.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=64)


linear_model.fit_generator(train_batches, train_batches.n, 
                           validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=test_batches.n, 
                           epochs=1)
```

When I am running this test script it uses the GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

I am also using nvidia-docker, which works when running their test docker images.

My Dockerfile looks basically like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel-ubuntu16.04

### basic utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get --assume-yes upgrade && \
    apt-get --assume-yes install binutils build-essential curl gcc git g++ \
        libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev libzmq3-dev pkg-config make nano rsync \
        software-properties-common unzip wget && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



### anaconda & tensorflow
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget "https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh" -O "Anaconda.sh" && \
    bash "Anaconda.sh" -b && \
    echo "export PATH=\"$HOME/anaconda3/bin:\$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" && \
    conda install -y bcolz && \
    conda upgrade -y --all && \
    pip install Pillow && \
    pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl && \
    pip install keras
```

Why is my Python script at the top not using the GPU properly? I can see that it allocates ~ 3 gigabytes of memory but it does not use it for processing.

Comment: In `fit_generator`, you set number of epoches to be 1. GPU usually takes quite some time to initialize and load data for the first run. It is much faster for the following epoches. So you may try setting number of epoches to a larger number to see how is the performance later.

Comment: Not familiar with Keras. But are you able to add "config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)" somewhere in Keras, or using a Keras equivalent?